# Removing embedded texture in an illustration

Tags: adobe-photoshop

We hired overseas illustrators for a project who are now MIA. We have a color illustration with texture on it, but only have a PSD file they've already flattened, so we can't get to the original texture layer to remove it.

Is there any workaround to get the texture off the illustration?
Thanks.

Comment: Everything is possible... depends on the amount of work. Care to share a screenshot? It would help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this sounds overtly simplistic. But if its a transparent background, you could just apply a color overlay?
If its a multicolored but flat illustration, the other way around is to manually fill in the colors.